# Determine if application is in foreground or background or killed state

Tags: android, android-intent, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to check if my android application is in background,foreground or killed state on notification received using the GCM notification method. This is to do different operations based on the state of the application.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option would be to overload the different activity methods that run on each [state change](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). From there you can read that variable in your gcm notification method, and act accordingly.